# What is the maximum payload in terms of mass delivered to LEO by launch vehicle which used pressure fed cycle in all stages?

Tags: propulsion, launch-vehicle, record

Launch vehicles can use pressure fed cycle in any stage of the rocket, but here i am interested for those vehicles which used this cycle in all stages. What is the current record in terms of mass of payload delivered to LEO for such vehicles? I don't count suborbital flights and vehicle must be launched from Earth. Also i don't count conceptual vehicles, only one which successfully delivered payload in LEO.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a vehicle? In other words, have there been any?

Comment: I am not sure, that's why i am asking. If correct that none of pressure fed vehicles reached LEO than  0kg is acceptable answer. I know for never flown concepts but thats not the point of question.

Comment: Disqualified for your question, but [OTRAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTRAG_(rocket)) and [Sea Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Dragon_(rocket)) were intended to launch to orbit on pressure fed engines. OTRAG never flew to orbit and Sea Dragon (which certainly would have had the payload record) was never built.

Comment: Was going to mention OTRAG, but Russell beat me to it.  It got to at least 150 km altitude, but not to orbital speed.  It was designed to carry 2 tons all the way to geostationary orbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is "0.0 kg".

Orbital launch vehicles with pressure-fed first stages are few and far between. *[Diamant](http://www.astronautix.com/d/diamant.html)* had that with its [Vexin](http://www.b14643.de/Spacerockets/Specials/European_Rocket_engines/engines.htm) engine, but solid upper stage.

I don't know of any successful orbital vehicle with all pressure-fed stages, but maybe there's an obscure one out there.

See also [Some examples of pressure fed engines used on launch vehicles](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18320/6944)